# how do I make jacoco add the tests files themselves to the coverage report

Tags: java, maven, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

In my sample maven project, I have this jacoco configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.4</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>jacoco-report</id>
      <phase>test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>report</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

which I got from https://automationrhapsody.com/automated-code-coverage-of-unit-tests-with-jacoco-and-maven/ (and then changed to the newest version)

It works great for the coverage of the implementation (src/main), but doesn't give me any coverage information for the tests themselves (src/test)

Although I agree that this is a sensible default, I would like to change it it one of my projects to tell me the coverage information for the tests as well.  Does anybody know how?

I have a full example here. https://github.com/alex028502/jacoco-example

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/271 as of today this feature is not provided by `jacoco-maven-plugin`, however [one of comments in this ticket also states](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/271#issuecomment-452087804)

> possible to generate report for test sources by using Ant tasks via `maven-antrun-plugin`

For example

```
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.8</version>
              <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                  <artifactId>org.jacoco.ant</artifactId>
                  <classifier>nodeps</classifier>
                  <version>0.8.4</version>
                </dependency>
              </dependencies>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                    <target>
                      <typedef resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml"/>
                      <report>
                        <executiondata>
                          <fileset dir="target" includes="jacoco.exec"/>
                        </executiondata>
                        <structure name="Coverage Report">
                          <classfiles>
                            <fileset dir="${basedir}/target/test-classes"/>
                          </classfiles>
                          <sourcefiles>
                            <fileset dir="${basedir}/src/test/java"/>
                          </sourcefiles>
                        </structure>
                        <html destdir="${basedir}/target/coverage-report/html"/>
                      </report>
                    </target>
                  </configuration>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
```

generates following report for your test

[image: report]

Answer (score 0):

Also, we can add in the jacoco plugin that how much minimum coverage we want in our project using limit and counter or how many max classes we can allow to skip.

follow sample of plugin:

```
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-check</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <rule>
                                    <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                    <limits>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>0</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>CLASS</counter>
                                            <value>MISSEDCOUNT</value>
                                            <maximum>50</maximum>
                                        </limit>
                                    </limits>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```